# mysqldump and flush tables with read locks

Tags: mysql

I'm running the `mysqdump` from server1 to server2

The mysqldump command I'm using is

```
mysqldump -q -u dump -p######## -h ###.###.###.### --add-drop-database --add-drop-table --set-charset --all-databases > dump.sql
```

and the user and privileges are correct.

When I run this I do get an output file (dump.sql) but it stops at 948,920 bytes and does not increase in size even if I leave it for 1 hour.

I have tried the mysqldump **8 times** now with the same message from the running process:

```
292186  root    localhost   RED Query   26  Waiting for release of readlock LOCK TABLES `OLD_RED_NOTES` READ /*!32311 LOCAL */,`RED_ADD` READ /*!32311 LOCAL */,`RED_COUNTRY` RE
```

If however I don't perform the **`FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;`** I can get a 7GB file without issue.

I simply cant understand why I cant get this with the table lock !

Been bashing Google for 48 hours with no joy ! Please help

Comment: sounds like it's deadlocking on something else having locked your old_red_notes table. any other users/processes hitting the database while you're trying to do the dump?

Answer (score 0):

Do "SHOW PROCESSLIST" as root to see what other processes are hitting your table and giving you the lock. If your tables are InnoDB, use SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS which will show the InnoDB locks and other information as well. If you are using MyISAM, "SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Table%'" will show you if you're hitting a lot of locks all the time or only with the dumps.